# Creating Connection pooling in java

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, connection, connection-pooling

I am creating a connection pooling in for my application..For that i just wan to know 
where to keep context.xml which has Resource name,username,password, driver Class Name

what s the difference when i keep the context.xml in tomcat and keeping in my project META-INF??

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question... keep the context.xml in META-INF and read it using JNDI. Keeping context.xml in tomcat as far as I know it done only if you want to use tomcat to handle your database connection. Keeping the context.xml in META-INF would make it easier for you to read and manage your connections.